# phpList mails rejected (possibly caused by exchange server)

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, phplist

I used an old version of phpList until it stopped working (certainly due to some internal server updates) and thus updated to version 3.0.5 last week. Everything went fine and I was even able to send out a few test mails.

Today, I tried to send a bigger amount of mails which caused bad headaches. I wanted to send about 2,800 mails and these are listed as "successfully sent" under Campaigns. But in the course of the day I received more and more "failure email notifications" in my inbox (now at about 1,100) with the following contents (translated and improved format by me):

> Error with sending a message to the following recipients or lists: xyz123@aol.com
>
> The email address of the recipient has not been found in the email
>   system of the recipient. Microsoft Exchange will not try to resend
>   this message. Check the email address and try to resend this message
>   or contact your system administrator with the following diagnose text:
>   **The following organisation has rejected your message**:
>   mailin-02.mx.aol.com.
>
> Diagnose information for administrators: Generating sever:
>   abc987.kasserver.com xyz123@aol.com mailin-02.mx.aol.com
>
> **Recipient address rejected**: aol.com> #SMTP#
>
> Original message header:
>
> - Return-Path: 
>     -Received: by abc987.kasserver.com (Postfix, from userid 548) id AE51891; Mon, 4 Nov 2013 10:30:33 +0100 (CET)
> - To: xyz123@aol.com
> - Subject: =?UTF-8?ourSubject?=
> - Received: from Customer-Transfer.telemaxx.net [85.115.31.102] by www.ourdomain.de with HTTP; Mon, 04 Nov 2013 09:10:58 +0100 Date: Mon,
>     4 Nov 2013 09:11:27 +0100
> - From: Our Newsletter Name
> - Reply-To: Our Newsletter Name
> - Message-ID:
> - X-Priority: 3
> - X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.5 (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/)
> - X-phpList-version: 3.0.5
> - X-MessageID: 247
> - X-ListMember: xyz123@aol.com
> - Precedence: bulk
> - Bounces-To: me@ourdomain.de
> - *[...]*
> - MIME-Version: 1.0
> - Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
> - Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the server, so all I can offer is the following additional information:

- PHP version: 5.3.18
- MySQL version: 5.1.70

Any help is greatly appreciated, even if it's only a guess or little hints.

Comment: Check if your mail server(s) is/are on an email blacklist: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: Your "To:" header is blank. Did you censor that? Or is it actually blank?

Comment: @MosheKatz: I've checked my hoster's adress (all-inkl.com) and supposedly it's mailserver (kasserver.com/85.115.31.102). Only the first one is listed on the "RATS Dyna" blacklist (Return codes were: 127.0.0.36). What can I deduce from that?

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Yes, I hurried a little too much. Of course there is an actual recipient ("xyz123@aol.com"). I edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that AOL is using the `RATS-Dyna` blacklist and rejected your messages because you are on that list.

You are probably on the list because your IP address resolves backwards to `dd10.kasserver.com`, which looks like a "generic_addressing_style.upstream_provider.com" that RATS-Dyna blocks.

To solve that, you need to contact your provider and see if they can give you a PTR record to point the address to a "real"-looking name.  Probably just changing it from `dd...` to something else more complex will help.

Another possible way to get on the RATS-Dyna list is if you send mail too fast.  You need to be careful not to look like a spam bot.

---

**How fast is too fast?**

Short answer: There is no hard number.  You might have to experiment.

Long answer:  Here are some mail policies from several hosting companies which might give you an idea.  However, note how large the range is:

- HostGator - [500/hr](http://www.hostgator.com/mailpolicy.html)
- Gmail - [No hard limit over time, but does limit addressees per-message](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en).  Note that Gmail also has a very good [Guide for Bulk Message Sending](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126) which might help you keep your messages out of spam folders.
- Google Apps - [varies](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hlrm=en)
- MDD Hosting - [200/hr](http://www.mddhosting.com/mailpolicy.php)
- [Many More](http://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/lists-of-hosts-and-their-sending-limits/)

Note that some services like Amazon Simple Email Service can theoretically send much faster than the services listed above.  That is because Amazon puts a lot of effort into maintaining the reputation of their servers and the receiving mail servers "know" that.  Your basic web-hosting-with-email just isn't on the same level, so take it easy.

Open-source mailing list software [Dada Mail](http://dadamailproject.com/) defaults to sending a single message every 8 seconds, for a total of 450 messages/hour.

Comment: Summing up:
1) Contacting my provider to get a PTR record like 'myCompany.provider.com' (would that be better?)
2) I should limit my number of mails per minute/hour (what's a 'good' value here?)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Clarifies this a little... Funnily enough I got an email by my provider which says "Hey, our domain is not on ANY blacklist!".... Actually he's right. Neither dd10.kasserver.com, nor dd10902.kasserver.com (where we are hosted), neither our domain itself are listed on any blacklist anymore (We've checked this, right?). I'm really confused now... Is there something like 'temporary blacklisting'?

Comment: Yes, there is such a thing as temporary blacklisting.  It's actually pretty common, because it reduces false positives.  All you need to worry about is not getting *bask* on a blacklist. (Note: it is possible that someone else already asked for the blacklist removal and that's why they said they aren't on one.)

Comment: Looks like a never-ending story... I'll give your suggestions a try - and thus mark your answer as the solution of my problem (which it hopefully will become). Thanks!